# Speeding up a program that counts numbers divisable by 3 or 5

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, numbers, division

I'm trying to write a simple program that counts numbers that are divisible by 3 or 5 in a specific range. However, the program still fails to meet the desired execution time for some inputs.
Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    unsigned long long int a=0, b=0, count=0;

    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    
    unsigned long long int i=a;

    while(i<=b){
        if(i%3==0){
            ++count;
        }
        else if(i%10==0 || i%10==5) ++count;
        ++i;
    }
    printf("%d", (unsigned long long int) count);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried the version below too because I thought it will help with big numbers, but the results are still quite the same.

```
#include <cstdio>
 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    unsigned long long int a=0, b=0, ile=0;

    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    
    for(unsigned long long int i=a; i<=b; ++i){
        unsigned long long int liczba = i, suma=0;
        while(liczba>0){
            suma+=liczba%10;
            liczba = liczba/10;
        }
        if(suma%3==0){
            ++ile;
        }
        else if(i%10==0 || i%10==5) ++ile;
    }
    printf("%d", (unsigned long long int) ile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Free clue: this is a mathematical formula that calculates the result. Any attempt to check each number manually, in the range, will not work. A single formula gives you the answer. This is a coding puzzle from a web site that has a list of silly coding puzzles that are based on mathematical or programming tricks. If you don't know the mathematical or a programming trick your program is always too slow. No optimization will help. Unfortunately, that web site is just list of dumb coding puzzles; to learn C++ or all of these mathematical algorithms -- that can only be done from a good textbook.

Comment: `i%10` is the wrong approach to test if a number is "divisible by 5"  Your test `i%10==5` is true only for half of the positive integers that are divisible by five.

Comment: Basically just divide the difference from the start to the end of the range by 3 and 5 then make some adjustments for whether the numbers at the ends of the ranges are multiples of 3 and 5

Comment: Where did the divisible by 10 requirement come from?  I don't see it in your post.  FYI, any number divisible by 10 is also divisible by 5.

Comment: Make sure you are compiling with compiler optimizations enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The divisibility of numbers by 3 and 5 repeats every 15 numbers.

See, illustration

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 
X        X     X  X        X  X     X    
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
X        X     X  X        X  X     X
```

Now, you need to use this fact to only check up to 15 numbers at the beginning of the range, up to 15 numbers at the end of the range and perform a multiplication to compute the rest real quick.

Comment: Come on. You don't even need to do "check up to 15 numbers" at the beginning or the ending rnage. Just use a simple formula to get the number of hits from 0 'till the ending number, then use the same formula to get the result from 0 'till one less than the starting number, and then use a highly advanced mathematical trick that's known as "subtraction" to calculate the answer. The End.

Comment: Baby steps :-). We're starting from a point where OP iterates over all numbers. I felt like helping them figure out the main trick would have the highest pay-off. But yeah, you are right, it can be improved further

Answer (score 1):

Let`s say that we have a function ansBefore, that returns the answer from 1 to X
Then the result is ansBefore(b) - ansBefore(a-1) (for a>0 and b>0 and a<=b)

```
#include <cstdio>
 
using namespace std;


unsigned long long ansBefore(unsigned long long x) {
    return x/3 + x/5 - x/15;
}

int main(){
    
    unsigned long long a=0, b=0, ile=0;

    scanf("%llu%llu", &a, &b);
    
    printf("%llu", ansBefore(b) - ansBefore(a-1));
    

    return 0;
}
```

Btw, please use %llu for unsigned long long, not %d